# How to display selected Item in spinner with custom adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

I am trying to implement a spinner in my android app with a custom adapter. I am able to populate the spinner with data, but I am not able to select the data and have it display on the spinner. I also want to display a text like 'Select' when the user hasn't clicked on it.
Here is my custom adapter-

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

import java.util.List;

public class TransactionModeSpinnerAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<TransactionModeDetails> {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public TransactionModeSpinnerAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<TransactionModeDetails> transactionModeDetails) {
        super(context, resource, transactionModeDetails);
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View rowView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_spinner_transaction, null,true);

        TransactionModeDetails transactionMode = getItem(position);
        TextView txnMode_spn = rowView.findViewById(R.id.spntransaction_tv_txnName);

        txnMode_spn.setText(transactionMode.getTransactionModeName());

        return rowView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        if(convertView == null){
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_spinner_transaction, parent,false);
        }

        TransactionModeDetails transactionMode = getItem(position);
        TextView txnMode_spn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spntransaction_tv_txnName);

        txnMode_spn.setText(transactionMode.getTransactionModeName());

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Below is where I am using it-

```
public void populateActiveTransactionModes(){

        List<TransactionModeDetails> getTransactionModes = dbHandler.getActiveTransactionModes();

        transactionModeListAdapter = new TransactionModeSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_spinner_transaction, getTransactionModes);
        selectTransactionMode.setAdapter(transactionModeListAdapter);

    }
```

Comment: did you tried setting up onItemSelectedListener for your spinner?

Comment: I didn't, but I found out the problem. It was working properly, the problem was that I was not able to see it because only the white part of the spinner layout was visible on the spinner. I have resized the layout and the spinner and now it is working great.